# Bootstrap center div with right div beside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my html:

```
<div class="welcome-banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 welcome-msg">
                <?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?><?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 welcome-cart">
                <?php $_cartQty = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount(); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCartUrl(); ?>"> <?php echo $this->__('View Cart'); ?>
                    (<?php echo $_cartQty ?: '0'; ?>)</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is what shows up:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now my issue is.. The "welcome message" text isnt centered on the entire bar, just that div of `col-md-10`

Is there a way to do this so the `view cart (0)` is aligned to the right, and the `welcome message text` is centered ?

The whole thing has to be on one line like below:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: define your .welcome-cart class text-right class or define css text-align:right;

Comment: if you are using bootstrap in css class add class="col-md-2 welcome-cart pull-right "

Comment: What actually is your problem now? Your text only gets centered inside of your `col-md-10`?

Comment: @Aer0 ignore my edit, you answered my question :D

Comment: Glad I could help. If you still want to use some kind of responsiveness, you will have to wrap your content inside the full grid size, including all 12 parts. So just like `col-md-12` instead of 10.

Comment: @Aer0 Awesome thanks, I will use that too if I need it

Comment: @Aer0 Hey, I was going through it again, and it doesn't center it properly either.. It's not fully centered.  

http://i.imgur.com/V8FOg7U.jpg - as you can see, the center text isn't actually in the center of the brown bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnk378xb/).

What exactly happens there is, that you firstly center the whole `div`s text as centered. Afterwards, simply `pull-right` the content you want to have sticky at the right side.

Of course, this requires Bootstrap. For a non Bootstrap solution, simply use `text-align: center;` to get your `div`s content centered, and `float: right;` for your content which has to stick at the right hand side.

**EDIT:** As far as Brandon mentioned, this isn't working properly. The problem in here is that both elements are in the same container and also share the same relativity. In other words, the right pulled span is getting display after the centered text, which obviously leads to a false behaviour, as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tnk378xb/3/).

Since you want to have them totally independent of each other, you have to consider using `absolute` positioning. This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnk378xb/4/) shows how to do so.

**Note:** Keep in mind your parent container needs a relative positioning. Else, you may mess around with your styling.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note, doing so you don't need `<div class="col-md-10 welcome-msg">` anymore inside of your row. And finally, if my answer helped you, I would be glad to get it marked as answered. :)

Comment: Hey, I was going through it again, and it doesn't center it properly either.. It's not fully centered.  

http://i.imgur.com/V8FOg7U.jpg - as you can see, the center text isn't actually in the center of the brown bar

Answer (score 1):

As everyone mentioned, you can use `pull-right` class.

```
<div class="welcome-banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 welcome-msg text-center">
                <?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?><?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>

                <?php $_cartQty = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount(); ?>
                <a class='pull-right' href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCartUrl(); ?>"> <?php echo $this->__('View Cart'); ?>
                    (<?php echo $_cartQty ?: '0'; ?>)</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://www.bootply.com/wycAs23Jcn for a Bootstrap example solution.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 welcome-msg">
          <p>welcome message</p>
          <span class="pull-right">view cart (0)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you wanted to center the "welcome message", you should use *class="col-md-12"*.

Then add your code inside the div which has the text-align: center style.

Then simply add *pull-right* to your text-aligned right content.

Comment: Hey, I was going through it again, and it doesn't center it properly either.. It's not fully centered.  

http://i.imgur.com/V8FOg7U.jpg - as you can see, the center text isn't actually in the center of the brown bar